# drag and drop. Расчет формулы

Tags: javascript, формулы, drag-n-drop

Код, к сожалению, приложить не могу.

Есть реализация ползунка, при перемещении которого меняется возраст человека. Длина блока, по которому перемещается ползунок 166px. Минимальный возраст - 16 лет, максимальный - 80. Т.е. =>

```
0px   = 16 лет
166px = 80 лет
```

У меня возникла проблема с составлением формулы, которая будет рассчитывать возраст, в зависимости от расположения ползунка, например,

```
33 px = x лет
```

Подскажите, куда двигаться, чтобы правильно составить формулу?

Пробовал так:

```
80 лет = 166px
x лет = 33px
=> x = (80 * 33) / 166
```

В итоге это почти  правильное решение, но есть минус, `1px != 16`

Comment: судя по всему 16 лет должно быть не на 1px а на 0px - это же точка отсчета и минимум. Поэтому зачем на 1px его ставить? Получается, что `длина_ползунка / (max_лет - min_лет)`.... но там еще с округлением надо будет баловаться..... в итоге 0px - 16лет, 2,6px - 17 лет, 5,2px - 18лет и т.д...... окруление нужно будет т.к. нет десятичных пискселей

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, верно, отсчет должен от 0 идти. Спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: Вообще, чтобы не мучиться с вычислением пикселей, можно взять `<input type="range"`, установить минимум, максимум, шаг. и просто стилизовать его)

Comment: Пиксели вычислить несложно, сложно по пикселям вычислить года) При перемещении ползунка меняются пиксели от 1 до 166 и затем, по пикселям определить возраст ) `range` здесь не подойдет, так как используются два ползунка, между которыми промежуток возраста

Comment: Как раз самое оно. Т.к в range совершенно точно известно на какой шкале находится какое значение. то есть если у нас минимум 16 и максимум 80 и шаг, например, 4, то так и пишется `<input type="range" min="16" max="80" step="4"/>`. Всё.... дальше при событии `onchange` инпута просто пересчитывается значение..... может я не совсем понимаю, что значит `используются два ползунка, между которыми промежуток возраста`. Но пока проблем с этим не вижу. Вижу наоборот, только плюсы)) https://codepen.io/gearmobile/pen/beVNqj ..... тем более слайдеру можно поставить через css длину 166px и не париться....

Comment: Один ползунок устанавливает минимальный возраст среди возможного, второй - максимальный, например, 18-22, на допустимом отрезке 16-80. Да, `range` хорошая штука, но не для этой задачи :) Может, конечно, я ошибаюсь )

Comment: А, ну, тут чуть посложнее.....тут можно например двумя слайдерами эмулировать один. как пример https://leaverou.github.io/multirange/ .... можно в код страницы глянуть (там есть у инпутов классы original и ghost).....хотя всё равно для меня это проще, чем странный расчет пикселей и опор на них. но решать-то вам) удачи

Comment: спасибо, и вам ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Длина в пикселях 166 = количеству лет (80 - 16 = 64), т.е. `166 = 64`.

Получается, в пикселях 1 год = 2,59375

Формула итоговая должна быть такая: `лет = (текущее_положение_ползунка / 2,59375) + 16`

Comment: Это статика. Здесь же пиксели меняются при перемещении ползунка, т.е. от 1 до 166 он может остановиться, например, на 134px, и уже по этим пикселям(134) определить возраст

Comment: Не понял, и что? подставьте 134 в формулу - будет 67 лет, что не так?

Comment: ааа, понял, ну да сорр, там не длина_ползунка, а текущее_положение_ползунка естественно..

Comment: Подскажете, как обратно, из возраста пиксели получить?

Comment: @Amandi (возраст - 16) * 2,59375

Comment: точно, спасибо :)

Comment: @Amandi не за что =)